# python Selenium options drop down

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python. I have a code in R that I am trying to replace with a python
script. I am running into issues getting python to select a value from a drop
down menu.

This is the code in R that worked:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id = 'groupby1']/option[@value = 'ReportDate']")$clickElement()
```

This is the HTML code:

```
select style="" class="dropdown" name="groupby1" id="groupby1" accesskey="" waffle_affected_fields=""

option value="ReportData">Report Date</option>
```

here are a couple things I tried after searching how to do this in python and I
keep running into errors.

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='groupby1']/option[@value='ReportDate']").click()
NameError: name 'find_element_by_xpath' is not defined

Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#groupby1")).select_by_value('ReportDate').click()
NameError: name 'Select' is not defined
```

Any help is appropriated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) doesn't have `click()`. Use it like this

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id('groupby1')).select_by_value('ReportDate')
# or by text
Select(driver.find_element_by_id('groupby1')).select_by_visible_text('ReportDate')
```

Comment: Here is the error message:     elem= Select(driver.find_element_by_id('groupby1')).select_by_value('ReportDate')
NameError: name 'Select' is not defined. Is there something I need to import other than  from selenium import webdriver?

Comment: @symn28 Did you import select? `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select`

Comment: I just did and now it works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

These functions are properties of your `webdriver` instance. You need to do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='groupby1']/option[@value='ReportDate']").click()
```

See the [getting started page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html) for examples.